Existence and moment estimation for a linear stochastic differential equation (SDE) with random coefficients
Let $W$ be one-demensional Brownian motion, and suppose $X$ satisfies the following SDE
$$
\mathrm{d}X_s=(A_sX_s+B_s)\mathrm{d}s+(C_sX_s+D_s)\mathrm{d}W_s, \quad X_0=x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n,
$$
where $A, C\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $B,D\in\mathbb{R}^n$ are adapted stochastic process and have continuous path, and satisfy
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{0\leq t\leq T}|E_t|^N\right]<\infty, \quad \forall n\in\mathbb{N} \,\,\text{and}\,\, E=A,B,C,D.
\end{equation}
My question is how to prove or give a counterexample to
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{0\leq t\leq T}|X_t|^N\right]<\infty, \quad \forall n\in\mathbb{N}.$$
In the case of $A$ and $C$ are bounded, this can be done by Yong's inequality and Gronwall's inequality. But under the contions in this question, I don't know how to prove that.
It seemes that $B=C=D=0$ is a counterexample if $A$ has no exponential moment. I want to konw that if we suppose that $A,B,C,D$ have exponential moment, will the conclusion holds?
Many thanks for the help.

Take $B=C=D=0$ and $A$ constant, but having no exponential moments...

I get that.  What if $A,B,C,D$ have exponential moment.
